# There are "gaps" between rows in my masonry cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I have created this site:
https://jsfiddle.net/1pvk13o8/

I am using jquery masonry, all seems to work great but there are gaps or holes of white space between some of the rows , any help? 
I want everything to be aligned as it should

All the files together are in the jsfiddle (really short amount of code)

JS:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.card').masonry();
  }) < /script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I did linked all the assets, please check on the left where it says "external assets" you will see 5 assets there including jquery, materialize, masonry, etc.....if you expand the html part you will see the masonry working perfectly just with the white/spacing gaps that I am trying to fix..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Script not working. Use code like this:

```
$('.videos').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.card'
});
```

CSS

```
.card  {
  float: left;
   width: 300px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

Also need to include Jquery file if you didn't.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly but now there is no space between the cards , do you know how to make a few px of space between each card element? before that I had  .card + .card {margin-left: 10px}

Comment: Here, I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1pvk13o8/11/) with necessary CSS, fixed links to resource (initial one had broken link to jQuery) and Gaurav's masonry init.

Comment: There should have 10px space between the cards because of margin in css. You can check @Andrei fiddle linked above or you can use 'gutterWidth' option in masonry script. Check documention here http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/options.html#gutterwidth

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using CSS columns instead of masonry:

```css
.videos {
  -webkit-columns: 290px 4;
  -moz-columns: 290px 4;
  columns: 290px 4;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  column-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}

.card {
  width: 300px;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  left: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

/* below is Material Icons font family form Google, which couldn't be linked directly */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v10/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">Surf Videos</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="sass.html"><i class="material-icons">search</i></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="videos">
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at asdadasdsadsadsad ajdasjdjas nasdn asdj asdj asd ansdja djasd small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient becaus little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient becaus little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient becaus little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient becaus little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud eiatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
          deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Iconvenient becaus little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-image">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixed-action-btn" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </a>
</div>
```